# Fancypagestyle in \DeclareOption

Tags: fancyhdr, documentclass-writing, class-options

In my class I want to define the page layout first during`\DeclareOption` and then modify it during a `\newenvironment` declaration. For that I wanted to use the `fancyhdr` package. Now my problem is that a) I have to load the packages after `\ProcessOptions` and b) I do not know how I can modify or extend the page properties on the fly in the `\newenvironment` environment. What I basically want (pseudocode):

```
\DeclareOption{test}{%
    \fancypagestyle{aSix}{%
    }
} 
\ProcessOptions
\newenvironment{test2}{%
\fancypagestyle{aSix2}{
%Takes the pagestyle aSix and update it with additional values}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Such fragments are not really useful :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: That was just an approach to clarify my problem, should I try to do a complete MWE (even if it does not compile)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use another approach with a `conditional`, say `\ifaSix` and setting this to `true` with `\aSixtrue` if the class option is used.

Rudimentary class

```
\ProvidesClass{ishouldgivemoreinformation}

\newif\ifaSix
\DeclareOption{aSix}{\global\aSixtrue}


\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{aSix}{%
  \fancyhead[C]{Foo}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{5pt}
}

\ifaSix
\fancypagestyle{aSix2}{%
  \pagestyle{aSix}%
  \fancyfoot[c]{Foobar}%
  % Some updates here
}
\else
\fancypagestyle{aSix2}{%
  \pagestyle{aSix}%
}
\fi

\endinput
```

`driver.tex`

```
\documentclass[aSix]{ishouldgivemoreinformation}


\pagestyle{aSix2}
\begin{document}
FOO
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks good, I'll try it!

Comment: @arc_lupus: Alright. I believe the `\if....` test can be even done within the `\fancypagestyle{aSix2}` definition, instead of using the definition twice (untested)

Comment: @arc_lupus: Any news on this?

Comment: Not yet, will test it later this afternoon due to work...

Comment: @arc_lupus: You're welcome!